# Convergent of limit in a dynamical system

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes, chaos-theory

I would like to find the stability of the fixed point for

> $\dot{y}=\mu-y^{2}$ with initial conditon $y\left ( 0 \right )=y_{0}$

Given the identity

> $\frac{1}{a^{2}-b^{2}}=\frac{1}{2a}\left ( \frac{1}{a-y}+\frac{1}{a+y} \right )$

and ignoring the 'negative' root for ease of convenience, the solution is

> $y\left ( t \right )=\frac{\left [ \frac{y_{0}+\sqrt{\mu}}{y_{0}-\sqrt{\mu}} \right ]\sqrt{\mu}e^{2\sqrt{\mu}t}-\sqrt{\mu}
> }{1+\left [ \frac{y_{0}+\sqrt{\mu}}{y_{0}-\sqrt{\mu}} \right ]\sqrt{\mu}e^{2\sqrt{\mu}t}-\sqrt{\mu}
> }$

The limit as time  tends to $\pm \infty$ yields 
$-\sqrt{\mu}$

It seems that the point $-\sqrt{\mu}$ is stable but what about $+\sqrt{\mu}$?
Have all stones been flipped?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An important idea of the subject is that it is not useful to compute solutions to determine their behaviour. This is explained in every decent source of notes on the subject hence one must ask, which texts are you following?

Comment: I'm following the lecture notes provided by my professor. This question came up in a tutorial.

Comment: Hmmm... And they do not explain how to bypass explicit computations? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: Succinctly, the notes provided an explanation as to how fixed points for a flow can be identified, how the an increasing an decreasing function can provide insights into the direction of a value, utilising geometric ideas to exploit the direction of a flow, and, for more complicated cases like determining the behaviour of a system in the neighbourhood of a fixed point how identifying the eigenvalues of a Jacobian provides insights as to the stability of a node (which of course implicitly reveals the flow).@Did
So no, to my best understanding, it doesn't-at least not for question of this natur

Comment: Funny, the tools you describe in your comment are exactly those designed to avoid any computation except the determination of the roots of $F(y)=0$ and of the sign of $F(y)$ between these roots. So, sorry, but "to (the) best (of your) understanding, it (very much) does, (especially) for question(s) of this natur(e)".

Comment: Note: my previous comment applies to the differential equation $\dot y=F(y)$ hence, in your situation, $F(x)=\mu-x^2$ for every real number $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\dot{y}=0$ at $y=\pm \sqrt{\mu}$, so there are two equilibrium points in the system.

To check their stability we can look at the linearized system about each point. The Jacobian of this system is simply $J = -2y$.

So for $y=\sqrt{\mu}$, the linearized system is $\delta\dot{y}=-2\sqrt{\mu}\delta y$ where $\delta y = y- \sqrt{\mu} $. The solution for this linear system is $\delta y(t)=e^{-2t\sqrt{\mu}}\delta y_0$ so as $t \to \infty$, $y(t) \to \sqrt{\mu}$

If you do the same thing for the second fixed point $y=-\sqrt{\mu}$ you get $\delta y(t)=e^{2t\sqrt{\mu}} \delta y_0$. So solutions diverge away from $-\sqrt{\mu}$ as $t$ increases. i.e. the equilibrium point is unstable.

Finally note that this analysis assumes $\mu\geq 0$. For $\mu<0$ there are no equilibrium points. Thus, as $\mu$ passes through zero, the stability of the system changes in what is known as a saddle-node bifurcation.

Comment: Shouldn't your Jacobian be a matrix?
My lecture notes are going in, perhaps, a slightly different direction to your explanation.
I am suggested to evaluate the Jacobian of the given flow function at the fixed point. 
The Jacobian A = $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
 0&-2 y 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Your system consists of only one state, so you have a 1-dimensional system and the associated Jacobian will be a matrix of size $1x1$. In your example above the first of row of $A$ does not add any information.